# How to add modified php in child theme?

Tags: child-theme, parent-theme

I have lot of modification in my php parent theme. How to save it to the child theme that I have? So, if ever the theme have some new version the php files that I modified would not affect. Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper way to make a tweaked theme into child-theme setting?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145045/proper-way-to-make-a-tweaked-theme-into-child-theme-setting)

Answer (score -2):

Just add a functions.php in your child theme folder and put your code in it.

Comment: even I modify the footer.php and index.php? Only functions.php I will copy?

Comment: And/or just copy any other file from your parent theme to your child theme folder and make those changes to these files.